# jQuery filter result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help. I get hash tags data from Tumblr via ajax and I loop through them to output them. Before I output the tags I want to do some filtering, and in the output if I have 4 of the same hash tag I need to only output it once.

Here is an example where without the filtering.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MZR2Z/126/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/testhermes.tumblr.com/posts",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        api_key : "d01TZzpbq12cD7Zv7dM4EwLndkAAIEsExnLl9PNvsHYuyuDwKq"
    },
    success: function(results){
        var posts = results.response.posts;
        var text ='';
        for (var i in posts)
        {
            p = posts[i];
            a = p.tags;


            for(var j in a) {
                c = a[j];
                text += '<a href="'+c+'">'+ c +'</a><br>';

                $("body").append(text);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to hold value in array and check every time you insert item whether it exist in array or not.

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/testhermes.tumblr.com/posts",
dataType: 'jsonp',
data: {
    api_key : "d01TZzpbq12cD7Zv7dM4EwLndkAAIEsExnLl9PNvsHYuyuDwKq"
},
success: function(results){
    var posts = results.response.posts;
    var text ='';
    var arr = [];
    for (var i in posts)
    {
        p = posts[i];
        a = p.tags;


        for(var j in a) {
            c = $.trim(a[j]);

            if(jQuery.inArray(c, arr) == -1)
            {

                arr.push(c);

                var text = '<a href="'+c+'">'+ c +'</a><br>';

                $("body").append(text);

            }


        }
    }
}
```

});

Here is [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9m7ua07u/) link.

Answer (score 2):

Simply keep track of tags you've already seen in an object, then only output the link if you haven't seen the tag before.

```
var seen_tags = {};
for (var i in posts)
{
    p = posts[i];
    a = p.tags;

    for(var j in a) {
        c = a[j];
        if(!(c in seen_tags)) {
            text += '<a href="'+c+'">'+ c +'</a><br>';

             $("body").append(text);
             seen_tags[c] = true;
        }
    }
}
```